# when upper limit of integral approaches to lower limit of definite integral, is integral vanish?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, limits, definite-integrals

I need to compute, $\lim_{n→∞}\int^{a+\frac{1}{n}}_a f(x)dx$. Given that, $F(x)$ antiderivative of continuous function $f$

My attempt:  $\lim_{n→∞}\int^{a+\frac{1}{n}}_a f(x)dx=\lim_{n→∞}(( F(a+\frac{1}{n})-F(a))=F(a)-F(a)=0$

Comment: Any function of the form $F(x) =\int_a^x f(t) \, dt$ is continuous by FTC and your result is an immediate consequence of continuity of $F$ at $a$. You don't need $f$ to be continuous, just let it be integrable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your considerations are correct.

Another approach: by the mean value theorem for integrals, there is $t_n \in [a,a+1/n]$ with

$$ \int^{a+\frac{1}{n}}_a f(x)dx=\frac{1}{n}f(t_n) \to 0$$

as $ n \to \infty.$